# What is the probability the team will win

Tags: probability

If a team 1 has a probability of p of winning against team 2. What is the probability "formula" that team one will win 7 games first.

There are no ties and the teams play until one t am wins 7 games

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that exactly $13$ games are played out, even though it is likely that the series will have been settled prior to the last game.  The advantage here is that we know that exactly one of the teams will have won  $7$ or more games and that determines the winner.  To finish, we remark that for Team $1$ to win the series, they must win between $7$ and $13$ games. Of course the probability that they win exactly $i$ games out of $13$ is $\binom {13}i p^i(1-p)^{13-i}$. Thus the answer is $$\sum_{i=7}^{13} \binom {13}i p^i(1-p)^{13-i}$$

Comment: I believe this is *the* correct answer.

Comment: @lulu , I got your comment, I agree

Comment: @Canardini  It's a seductive error...seems like something along those lines ought to work.  Maybe it's as simple as requiring that the team wins the seventh game on the last of the $7+k$.

Comment: Exactly ! I was looking for a simple solution ...

Comment: @Canardini  Well, I think your formula just needs $\binom {6+k}k$.  Can't say I thought that hard about it, but the logic seems correct...forcing the winning game $7$ to be in the last slot really ought to eliminate the multiple counting.

Comment: Indeed, I should work like that.  I am also  going to calculate the probability using the brute force method ( building the Markov Chain), and compare

Comment: See below, I fixed, it confirms your result

Answer (score 1):

A state $(a,b)$ where $a$ is the number of victories from team1 and $b$ from team2.

Team 1 wins if they reach the states $(7,0), (7,1),...,(7,6)$.

Each state $(7,k)$ are tied to $\binom{6+k}{k}$ possible scenarios of same probability of occuring, that is $p^7(1-p)^{k}$. Indeed, if the result is $(7,k)$ , it means that we played $7+k$ games, the $(7+k)^{th}$ game was won by team1, and we pick $k$ losses out of the $6+k$ remaining games.
Therefore $P((7,k))=\binom{6+k}{k}p^7(1-p)^{k}$.

Finally you probability is $$\sum_{k=0}^{6}P((7,k))=\sum_{k=0}^{6}{\binom{6+k}{k}p^7(1-p)^{k}}$$

Comment: This is not correct.  Try it with $p=.5$...the correct answer is obviously $.5$ by symmetry, but your value is a lot higher.  The problem is you multiply count.  For example, with $k=1$ you count the scenario in which our guys win the first seven and lose the eighth...but that scenario ended on the seventh game and was counted as $k=0$.

Comment: Fixed, it matches your results

Comment: Yes, I believe this version (+1)