# Probability of baseball team winning?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose the team wins $37\%$ of the time.

In order to "win", they must win best of 7 (or 4 games).

Answer the following questions to determine the probability that the team would have won a best of 7
playoff series (i.e., won 4 games) had they made the playoffs last season.

---

Rephrase this question in terms of sequences of 0s and 1s. What is the shortest length of a sequence?
What is the longest length of a sequence?

If we let 1 represent a win, and 0 a loss, then the shortest length of wins are 1111(4) and longest length of win is 0001111(7).

---

What are the number of sequences that correspond to them winning the series?

$\textbf{I don't know if this is right (my best guess)}$

If they win in 4 games, that's $\binom{4}{4}$ = 1.

If they win in 5 games, that's $\binom{5}{4}$ = 5.

If they win in 6 games, that's $\binom{6}{4}$ = 15.

If they win in 7 games, that's $\binom{7}{4}$ = 35.

Adding 1 + 5 + 20 + 35 = 56.

---

Calculate the number of sequences as they relate to this problem. (The answer is $not$ $2^7$ as not all series would last 7 games.)

and

Calculate the probability that they will win the series.

---

I need help on the last two, and is my 56 right?

Comment: Your counting is flawed.  You can't say that there are $\binom 64$ "ways to win in six games" because one of those ways would be $111100$ which would actually be a win in four games.  If you want to do it this way, you need to require that the last game played is a win.  Also, you can't just add these together because some strings are more probable than others.

Comment: Whats the best way to do it?

Comment: Well, you can do it your way if you correct for the errors I mentioned.  Personally, I prefer to imagine that all seven games are played regardless of the fact that the winner is probably decided before game $7$.  The winner of the series then wins at least $4$ of the games and you can count $4,5,6,7$ wins separately.

Comment: But the question specically says 4 games, if  you count 4,5,6,7 thats another question , is it not?

Comment: No.  The team that wins $5$ or more teams is the only team that gets $4$ (the other team only gets $2$ in this scenario).  That's the beauty of the method...the winner is correctly determined by simple majority.

Comment: to be specific, the probability of your team winning, with $p=.37$ is $\sum_{i=4}^7 \binom 7i p^i (1-p)^{7-i}$.  Nice clean sum.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this ... first out of the 7 games, we choose that the team wins 4,5,6,7. now we assume that they win, so we multiply by the probability that they win. It is $p^i$ since they are winning more then 1 game.... I understand that much, but could you explain the last bit $(1-p)^{7-i}$

Comment: I am counting the "exactly $i$ wins" scenarios.  Thus I need the good guys to win exactly $i$ and the bad guys to win the rest.

Comment: i see, and one more thing ... you said above that "

The team that wins $5$ or more teams is the only team that gets $4$ (the other team only gets $2$ in this scenario). That's the beauty of the method...the winner is correctly determined by simple majority."

Comment: Did you mean to say the team that wins $4*$ or more $games$

Comment: Sure. I was responding to your comment about $5,6,7$ wins, but yes:  if you play $7$ games, then exactly one team will win at least $4$ and that team is the winner.

Comment: This type of thinking makes more sense. thanks!

Comment: Could you perhaps put the answer in the question section so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that the clearest way to picture this is to imagine that all $7$ games are played out, despite the fact the winner may well have been decided before game $7$.  Indeed, with seven games played exactly one team will have won at least $4$ games and that team is, clearly, the first to have won $4$ games in the series.

With that in mind, the probability is easy to compute.  Assume $p$ is the probability that team $A$ wins any particular game (here $p=.37$) and let $p_i$ be the probability that $A$ wins exactly $i$ games in the series.  We see that $$p_i=\binom 7i p^i(1-p)^{7-i}$$ and we deduce that the probability that $A$ wins the series is $$\sum_{i=4}^7 p_i=\sum_{i=4}^7 \binom 7i p^i(1-p)^{7-i}$$

Worth mentioning [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051421/what-is-the-smallest-value-of-n-such-that-the-probability-that-a-wins-the-match/2051494#2051494) on a similar theme, wherein some useful approximation methods are discussed (relevant if $7$ is replaced by a large number).